# Bootstrap carousel without an active item

Tags: angular, carousel

I am doing a small gallery using carousel, however, I want it to be without an active image.. This is my code:

```
<div class="card bg-primary">
<h1 class="text-center bg-secondary text-white py-2">{{placeFromUrl}}</h1>
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Angular_full_color_logo.svg/250px-Angular_full_color_logo.svg.png" class="d-block w-50 mx-auto">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let image of placeImages">
                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{image.bytes}}" class="d-block w-50 mx-auto">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you leave it out?

Comment: it shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it without an active item but it won't display anything. The point of the active class is to set display: block; By default a carousel-item has display:none. By adding the active class you overwrite this property to make this image appear. You have a lot more work to do to get this working such as adding buttons or a timer to rotate through your items and changing the class to active.

Since you are using Angular I would recommend looking at ngb-carousel. It is about this simple.

```
<ngb-carousel class="mt-3 bg-dark">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of repo.currentPlace.images">
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img style="display: block;" [src]="image.url" alt="Random first slide" [class]="getRotateClass(image)">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <p>{{image.caption}}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

ngb-carousel is part of the ng-bootstrap package. Run the following in the project directory to install the package:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Then add NgbModule to you app module.

```
imports: [NgbModule, ...],
```

Full install and use directions along with full code examples are here:  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. this gives the console error: 1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: @RickAstley   I'd appreciate if you would mark that as answered or at least give it an up vote. Thanks,